# How to access parent usercontrol's datacontext.property in injected usercontrol using prism WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, prism-4

Hi I am working with WPF PRISM architecture.

I have two usercontrols:
UCParent--UCParentVM
UCChild  -- UCChildVM
Both have their own viewmodels.
Now that I  have injected UCChild into UCParent. But I want to access a property ("UCParent.DataContext.ProeprtyForChild") in the Parent usercontrol UCParent. How do I able to get the parent's DataContext.Property?

I Tried some relative source and element name binding. I think i am getting them completely wrong. So any clues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something sounds wrong here. For example, if a control is bound to an Object which contains a property of another object you can simply do: Property.SubProperty. If you have an ItemsControl, ItemsSource is set to a List of Objects and the ItemTemplate's DataContext is automatically the Object. But, you have a **Control** inside a control. You want the parent control, to modify the child controls datacontext? This sounds like a violation of MVVM. The VM of the Parent, would perhaps relate to the Child VM and interact with it directly? The link shouldn't go through UI controls?

Comment: I think your question has your parent and child crossed a few places.  If you can clean that up you can probably get a better answer.  (For Example you say you want to "access UCParent.DataContenct.PropertyForChild in UCParent"  That would be done via a simple binding: {Binding PropertyForChild})

Comment: @vaccano: I am trying to access parents property in Child so I should locate parents DataContext and then look for the Property "PropertyForChild"